# Is there any way to display the pages of a pdf file in mupdf, the same way as evince does?

Tags: debian, mupdf

I really like the simplicity of mupdf, but I can't seem to find any way to configure it a bit more to my liking. I'd like to have mupdf render the pages like evince does, so I don't have to switch pages using "." and ",", instead I just want to scroll through pages using "k" and "j". Is that in any way possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's just not possible, so I'll have to make do with the keybindings for switching pages, which is not that much of a pain either.